# VHDL: assigning to inout port from testbanch

Tags: vhdl, inout

I have VHDL module with bidirectional port which nested in Top module. In testbanch I try to assign data to signal which connected to bidirectional port of Top. But assigned data don't propogate to nested module bidirectional port, I see assigned data only at signal  of tb, not at port. Data from nested bidir port propogate to signal of tb sucsessfully. What is the cause of such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bidirectional ports of nested and top modules must be connected without intermediate signals. In case of intermediate signal the construction will work like unidirectional.